# CancellationTokenSource vs. volatile boolean

Tags: c#, task, volatile, cancellationtokensource

Are there any benefits for using a [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) over a  [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) boolean field for signalling a `Task` to finish?

Comment: A `CancellationToken` isn't meant to signal a thread to finish, it's meant to tell a `Task` to *cancel* it's operation. If you want a `Task` to return, simply use a `return` statement.

Comment: Since there are a load of standard C# threading classes (including Task) which use `CancellationTokenSource` in their interfaces, then that's what you should use.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov if I'm not mistaken, I still need to handle the way my tasks finish when using a CancelationTokeSource (i.e return or break)

Comment: `CancellationToken` is the only way you can transition your `Task` into a `Canceled` state. returning on a `bool` would transition it to a `Completed` state

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well, you could `throw TaskCanceledException` which would cause that to happen - but it would be a bit of an odd thing to do because the exception wouldn't contain a meaningful `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That wouldn't much sense though, would it? :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Simply throwing `TaskCanceledException` isn't enough. You need to pass a cancellation token, and same token has to be passed when you have started the task. Otherwise, Task will not be started, but faulted.

Comment: Arguably a duplicate of [Difference between CancellationTokenSource and exit flag for Task loop exit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27950848/3538012)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Of course yes. There are many. I'll list few.

- `CancellationToken` supports callbacks. You can be notified when the cancellation is requested.
- `CancellationToken` supports `WaitHandle` which you could wait for indefinitely or with a timeout.
- You can schedule the cancelation of `CancellationToken` using `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` method.
- You can link your `CancellationToken` to another, so that when one is cancelled another can be considered as cancelled.
- By `Task` if you mean `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` a volatile boolean cannot transition the state of the Task to cancelled but `CancellationToken` can.

Comment: And also [here's an interesting article from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx) explaining why he thinks you shouldn't use `volatile`.

Comment: That's very comprehensive, Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: to be fair, Eric's main objection seems to be that it's often very difficult to use `volatile` correctly, and that `lock` usually has sufficient performance, and is semantically easier to understand. A simple `volatile` flag to signal the termination of a task, while undesirable for other reasons, isn't what Eric seems to be concerned with in his article.

Comment: MatthewWatson's link is outdated, I update the link here ["Atomicity, volatility and immutability are different, part three"](https://ericlippert.com/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/)

Comment: I think @LouisGo response is the real answer here, better than the answer. Reading the answer, I think "Ok, I don't care, I'll use volatile." But reading Eric Lippert's blog, I think "Clearly there is complexity that I don't understand. I should use `Interlocked`, or `CancellationToken` instead."