# Does cancelling a CancellationToken cause a CancellationToken Exception?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cancellation-token

I have this code and I would like to get some clarification on the use of the CancellationToken.

I read this question about the difference between using a cancellation token and a flag:

[Difference between CancellationTokenSource and exit flag for Task loop exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950848/difference-between-cancellationtokensource-and-exit-flag-for-task-loop-exit)

One thing I noticed is that it mentions nothing about Exceptions.  So here's my question. **If the Disappearing() method is called then will this cause a TaskCanceledException() to occur and would this be a good reason to use the CancellationToken instead of a flag?**

```
public partial class PhrasesFrame : Frame
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public PhrasesFrame(PhrasesPage phrasesPage)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ShowCards(cts.Token).ContinueWith((arg) => { }));
    }

    public void Disappearing()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    public async Task ShowCards(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await PickCard();
        }
    }

    public async Task PickCard()
    {
        await ShowCard();
    }

    private async Task ShowCard()
    {
        await ShowPhrase();
        await ShowDetail();
    }

    private async Task ShowPhrase()
    {
        while (App.pauseCard || timer1Seconds > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000, tokenSource1.Token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // do action
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You cannot cancel a CancellationToken

Comment: Read the docs [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` by itself doesn't throw such exception, but it "moves" all related cancellation tokens to cancelled state. When some code notifies that cancellation token is now in cancelled state - it *might* throw such exception. If look at your example, this part will not throw such exception:

```
public async Task ShowCards(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await PickCard();
    }
}
```

Because you just don't throw it in this block. If however you instead did something like this:

```
public async Task ShowCards(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await PickCard();
    }
}
```

Then exception will be thrown, because, well, you throw it almost explicitly.

Now if look at another method from your example:

```
private async Task ShowPhrase()
{
    while (App.pauseCard || timer1Seconds > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, tokenSource1.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            // do action
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you were awaiting `Task.Delay(1000, tokenSource1.Token);` and then cancel `tokenSource1` - then `TaskCancelledException` will indeed be thrown immediately, without waiting for the whole duration of `Task.Delay`. This is something you cannot easily achieve with just a boolean flag. If you used `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and boolean flag - change to that flag won't be noticed until whole duration of sleep is finished.

So to answer your question: in your example exception might or might not be thrown, depending on what part of code is currently executing at the moment you cancel your `CancellationTokenSource` (I assume that using two cancellation token sources with names `cts` and `tokenSource1` is just a typo in your code, but if it's real code - then such exception cannot be thrown at all, because you cancel `cts` but `Task.Delay` waits on `tokenSource1`).